Inspecting files on an old Google App Engine app
Back in 2010 I created a few App Engine apps, including this one.  Over the years I've lost touch with the platform, only doing the mandatory updates Google requires to keep the app running.
Today I went to the app engine dashboard for the project, expecting to be able to inspect the data in the app files (BigQuery I think) the way I used to.  I clicked every link in sight but couldn't find any file inspector.
I realize the product and interface have evolved over the years, so perhaps there's a separate dashboard for storage.  Or maybe storage browsing was deprecated over the years.  But I'm at a loss.  Can somebody tell me where/how to find and browse my files?  Or explain that I can't do that anymore?

From what you're describing, you probably used the appcfg.py to deploy your App. It also allowed downloading your source code. appcfg.py has been deprecated & deploying to GAE now uses the gcloud SDK & Cloud Build and your files are stored for a default of 15 days (see the background section of this blog article from us for a detailed explanation). Summary - I don't believe you'll be able to download your source files. I'll be glad to be proved wrong though.

@NoCommandLine Thanks, but the files I'm talking about are data files that record player activity, mainly a record of their solutions to solitaire puzzles presented by the app.  It's those files that I used to be able to easily inspect, but now I can't find them anymore.  As for source files, I have them on my computer, so no worries there.

How did you store the data? If you stored them in datastore, they'll still be there - https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/databases/-default-

@NoCommandLine : now we’re talking. I’ve only got my phone right now, but the datastore URL looks like what I want. Will verify on my laptop tomorrow. As I speculated in the final OP paragraph, the datastore has its own dashboard.

Yes, it has its own page but things have changed. For one thing, multiple databases are now supported (you now have one explicitly named 'default'). So when you land on the datastore home page, you have to click on a database name (even if it's the default one) unlike previously when opening the datastore home page automatically loaded your datastore Kinds

@NoCommandLine thanks, this did the trick.  I now have to battle GQL to extract some data, but I've definitely found the files in datastore.  Feel free to convert your second comment to an answer and I'll gladly upvote and accept.

Moving from comments to answer

If your data was stored in datastore, they'll still be there. Navigate to  https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/databases/-default-

Note that datastore has changed from a few years back.
a) Multiple 'databases' are now supported (you now have one explicitly named 'default').
b) Now, when you land on the datastore home page, you have to click on a database name (even if it's the default one) unlike previously when opening the datastore home page automatically loaded your datastore Kinds


